# Display different Gridviews with a Dropdownlist onchange

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, html-select

I want to show different Gridviews when I select values from a dropdownlist.I use Visible="False" property to gridviews and I want to show only one on every value updated.
Example: when I select the Value "Points" I want to show GridView1 and when I select Names I want to show "GridView2". This is my ASP:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Stats_Ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Stats_Ddl_IndexChanged" >
    <asp:ListItem>POINTS</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>NAMES</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Visible="False"> blahblahblah1</asp:GridView>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" Visible="False">blahblahblah12</asp:GridView>
```

and c# is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Stats_Ddl_IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
}
```

Any suggestions for c# code?   thanks...

Comment: I rejected your edit combining the two answers.  Please leave comments to the poster about how you are using their code and collaborate, rather than change their answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi inside event SelectedIndexChanged

you should put for example

```
   If(Ddl.SelectedValue == "1"){

      GridView1.Visible = true;
      GridView2.Visible = false;

   }else{

      GridView1.Visible = false;
      GridView2.Visible = true;

   }
```

i see that you have a ListItem don't forget give to a value to property "Value" for example

Point = 1
Name = 2

Comment: Because I have 10 different values and 10 grid views.Is there any method to make all gridviews Visible = false; expect one for each time?

Comment: Well what happen if you create a simple method and inside this something like 

GridView1.Visible = false;
GridView2.Visible = false;
GridView3.Visible = false;
.
.
.
GridView10.Visible = false;

after when you select a new value call this method all gridview will visible false next to this method set visible the correct gridview

Comment: Yes.Is working. And if I want to set a default value selected when firstload the page?

Comment: Well if you are talking about the first change (Page_Load). First you need to set a Value in a new method for example

dropdownlist.Selected.Value = "MyValue"

don't forget this "MyValue" have to exists in your dropdownlist 

next to add a default value you have to copy the code from SelectedIndexChanged you remember all the If.. If.. etc in this method

and as this method is only to the first change don't forget the PostBack that is important

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SelectedItem.Text` property of `DropDownList` to branch

```
protected void Stats_Ddl_IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   if(Stats_Ddl.SelectedItem.Text == "POINTS")
       GridView1.Visible = true;
   else
   if(Stats_Ddl.SelectedItem.Text == "NAMES")
       GridView2.Visible = true;

}
```

Comment: THANK YOU MAN cAN YOU GIVE ME AN EXAMPLE WITH 3 POSSIBLE SELECTED VALUES?AND THE FIRST TO BE THE DEFAULT